# Por que o método "in" para verificar se um elemento pertence a uma coleção é tão lento?

Tags: python, algoritmo, desempenho

Eu estava tendo muita dificuldade de executar um código de forma eficiente e descobri que o problema estava em uma linha que usava o operador `in`. Então criei uma nova função que faz a busca por um match na lista de elementos de forma binária. Fiz uma análise da performance da minha função e do operador `in` e notei, para minha surpresa, que minha função era bem mais rápida. Aqui está meu código:

```py
import bisect
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import random
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

def belongs2(elements, value):
    index = bisect.bisect_left(elements, value)
    if index < len(elements) and elements[index] == value:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
def belongs2time(elements, value):
    start_time=time.time()
    index = bisect.bisect_left(elements, value)
    if index < len(elements) and elements[index] == value:
        True
    else:
        False
    return time.time() - start_time

def in_time(elements, value):
    start_time=time.time()
    value in elements
    return time.time() - start_time


# ### Timing belongs


number=random.choice(range(1000))
lengths=np.arange(100,100000,100)
time_belongs=[]
for lenght_list in lengths:
    numbers=[random.choice(range(1000)) for i in range(lenght_list)]
    numbers.sort()
    time_belongs.append(belongs2time(numbers, number))


# ### Timing in

number=random.choice(range(1000))
lengths=np.arange(100,100000,100)
time_in=[]
for lenght_list in lengths:
    numbers=[random.choice(range(1000)) for i in range(lenght_list)]
    numbers.sort()
    time_in.append(in_time(numbers, number))

fig, ax= plt.subplots()

ax.plot(lengths, time_belongs, label='belongs')
ax.plot(lengths, time_in, label='in')

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,-0.15),
          ncol=2, fontsize=14)

plt.yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não estou acostumado a fazer esse tipo de "análise de performance" (na verdade, é a primeira vez que faço isso), então posso ter cometido algum erro aqui e está chegando em uma conclusão errada. Mas se estiver certo, por que o operador `in` é tão lento? Eu esperava uma implementação mais eficiente de um método tão ubíquo ao python. Existe algum outro método `built-in` mais eficiente que o `in` para esse tipo de operação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiramente, se quer testar o tempo de execução, uma forma rápida e um pouco mais confiável é usar o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).

Dito isso, a busca usando o [módulo `bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) é mais rápida porque ela faz uma [busca binária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34410/112052), que é um algoritmo conhecido por ter complexidade O(logN). Ou seja, em uma lista com bilhões de elementos, ela precisa de pouco mais de 30 iterações no máximo. O único pré-requisito para que funcione adequadamente é que os elementos estejam ordenados.

Já o [operador `in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in), quando aplicado a listas, faz uma busca linear (e portanto [tem complexidade O(N)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)): ele parte do início da lista e vai testando os elementos um a um, até encontrar (ou até chegar ao final da lista, caso o elemento não exista). Apesar de mais lento que a busca binária, ele é o mais garantido caso a lista não esteja ordenada.

Enfim, não é que o `in` seja lento e ponto. Ele pode ser mais lento que outros algoritmos, como a busca binária, mas caso o uso desta não seja aplicável, ele ainda pode ser uma alternativa viável.

---

O seu teste re-escrito com `timeit` ficaria assim:

```
import bisect
import random

def belongs(elements, value):
    index = bisect.bisect_left(elements, value)
    return index < len(elements) and elements[index] == value

def in_time(elements, value):
    return value in elements

valores = range(10000)
number = random.choice(valores)
print(f'procurando por {number}')
numeros = list(valores)

from timeit import timeit

# executa 100 mil vezes cada teste
params = { 'number' : 100000, 'globals': globals() }
# imprime os tempos em segundos
print(timeit('belongs(numeros, number)', **params))
print(timeit('in_time(numeros, number)', **params))
```

Eu criei uma lista com todos os valores do `range`, assim já garanto que ela está ordenada (mas acho que tanto faz para fins de teste, poderíamos usar sua lista também).

Rodando, podemos ver que o `in` só é mais rápido se o número a ser procurado está logo no início da lista (se for um dos primeiros, o `in` encontra em menos iterações, já que a busca binária sempre parte do meio da lista).

---

Obs: se usar um [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) em vez de uma lista, a busca fica mais rápida:

```
valores = range(10000)
set_numeros = set(valores)
... restante do código igual ao exemplo acima

# adicionar mais um caso
print(timeit('in_time(set_numeros, number)', **params))
```

O detalhe, claro, é que um `set` não garante a ordem dos elementos e não permite valores repetidos. Se isso não for um problema, fazer a busca nele é mais rápida - conforme [a página já *linkada*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) anteriormente, a operação `in` em um `set` é O(1).

Comment: Muito interessante. Obrigado pela resposta detalhada. Eu conhecia o conceito de busca binária, mas como você sabe que o `in` é linear? Eu fiz o teste justamente pq eu não sabia como o `in` fazia a busca. Tinha uma forma de saber que ele era linear de ante-mão?

Comment: Desculpe, agora que vi que tinha essa informação na página que vc linkou

Comment: @Lucas Outra alternativa é [ver o código fonte](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Objects/listobject.c#L409) :-)